# Create Google Chart grouped bar overlapping stacked bar

Tags: charts, google-visualization, wkhtmltopdf

I having a hard time generating a chart bar using chartjs v2 in a pdf. whhtmltopdf do not support css animations so many people are suggesting to switch to Google Charts any one knows if we can do something like this graph using google charts? [Chart Image HERE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J5hwB.png)

I need to create a group bar overlapping a stacked bar. Thanks!!

Comment: check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132688/5090771)...

Answer (score -1):

Since Google Image Charts is deprecated, you can use [Image-Charts](https://www.image-charts.com) free API instead to display a grouped bar charts. However

I'm not sure if Google Charts even supported this kind of over-layer.

[image: grouped bar chart]

```
https://image-charts.com/chart
?chco=C5F4F5
&chd=a:2.5,3,5|4.5,3,3.4|2.4,2.6,2
&chl=27 Sep'18|05 Oct'18|04 Feb'20|27 Sep'18|05 Oct'18|04 Feb'20|27 Sep'18|05 Oct'18|04 Feb'20
&chxl=0:|Body|Male|Female|2:|Shots Values
&chs=900x313
&cht=bvg
&chma=0,50,50
&chxt=x,y,y
&chg=1,1
&icac=documentation
&icff=Average Sans
&icretina=1
&ichm=b2d2db40fe3d42c5469e54e3022d908c631e54a0321bd0d7902fe1cef540528b
```

Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder.