# Google Charts - Diff Chart with more than two datasets

Tags: google-visualization

Since `computeDiff()` only accepts two parameters I suppose that a Diff chart with more than two datasets is not supported officially by google charts, is there any workaround this?, a Diff chart is really useful for comparing different datasets, having a limitation of only comparing two at time seems really silly.

Comment: it's not a great option but --> [Google Chart - More then 1 difference column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49132688/5090771)

Comment: Yeah i saw that question, was hoping that there would be another way...., guess i'll try highcharts.